# Cache and Query a Dataset In Parallel Using Spark

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark

I have a requirement where I want to cache a dataset and then compute some metrics by firing "N" number of queries in parallel over that dataset and all these queries compute similar metrics just that the filters would change and I want to run these queries in parallel because response time is crucial and the dataset which I would like to cache will be always less than a GB in size.

I know how to cache a dataset in Spark and then query it subsequently, but If I have to run queries in parallel over the same dataset, how can I achieve the same ? Introducing alluxio is one way, but any other way we can achieve the same in Spark world ?

For example with Java, I can cache the data in memory and then by using multi threading I can achieve the same, but how to do it in Spark ?

Comment: what have you tried so far? You have to try first and then only ask for help

Comment: As I mentioned in the question, I know how to cache a dataset and execute queries on top of that, I need some direction on how to achieve the same in parallel in Spark, If i know the approach/concept to use, I would have done it already

Comment: by default : a query can run parallel on distributed dataset and queries run serially.  Now if you want to run multiple queries parallel then you will have to use threading concept. :)

Comment: Trying this right now http://www.russellspitzer.com/2017/02/27/Concurrency-In-Spark/ , will post my observations shortly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can be very simple to fire parallel queries in Spark's driver code using Scala's parallel collections. Here a minimal example how this could look like:

```
val dfSrc = Seq(("Raphael",34)).toDF("name","age").cache()


// define your queries, instead of returning a dataframe you could also write to a table etc
val query1: (DataFrame) => DataFrame = (df:DataFrame) => df.select("name")
val query2: (DataFrame) => DataFrame = (df:DataFrame) => df.select("age")

// Fire queries in parallel
import scala.collection.parallel.ParSeq
ParSeq(query1,query2).foreach(query => query(dfSrc).show())
```

EDIT:

To collect Query-ID and Result in a map you should so:

```
val resultMap  = ParSeq(
 (1,query1), 
 (2,query2)
).map{case (queryId,query) => (queryId,query(dfSrc))}.toMap
```

Comment: Awesome, Thanks, this is what am looking for, was not aware of parallel collections, will study about them.

Comment: If the query always returns a single value as output, any idea how can we collect the output of all the queries into a Map, where key represents query_id and value represents query output (single value)

Comment: @RajivChodisetti then use a map instead of foreach, e.g. `ParSeq(query1,query2).map(query => (getQueryId(query),query(dfSrc))).toMap`

Comment: yeah thought of using map, but query here is an Anonymous function right, couldn't figure out how to assign an unique identifier to each query

Comment: Thank you !!  Scala collections are amazing, looks like I need to practice n study Scala collections more thoroughly