# how to submit to spark for many jobs in one application

Tags: apache-spark

I have a report stats project which use spark 2.1(scala),here is how it works：

```
object PtStatsDayApp extends App {
    Stats A...
    Stats B...
    Stats C...
     .....     
}
```

someone put many stat computation(mostly not related) in one class and submit it using shell. I find it has two problems:

- if one stat stuck then the other stats below can not run
- if one stat failed then the application will rerun from the beginning

  I have two refactor solutions:
- put every stat in a single class ,but many more script needed. Does this solution get many overhead for submit so many?
- run these stat in parallel .Does this issue resource stress, or spark can hand it appropriately?

Any other idea or best practice? thanks

Answer (score 1):

There are several 3d party free Spark schedulers like Airflow, but I suggest to use Spark Launcher API and write a launching logic programmatically. With this API you can run your jobs in paralel, sequentially or whatever you want.

Link to doc: https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/api/java/index.html?org/apache/spark/launcher/package-summary.html

Efficiency of running your jobs in parallel mostly depends on your Spark Cluster configuration. In general Spark supports such kind of workloads.

Answer (score 1):

First you can set the scheduler mode to `FAIR`.  Then you can use parallel collections to launch simultaneous Spark jobs on a multithreaded driver.
A parallel collection, lets say... a Parallel Sequence `ParSeq` of ten of your `Stats` queries, can use a `foreach` to fire off each of the `Stats` queries one by one.  It will depend on how many cores the driver has as to how many threads you can use aimultaneously.  By default, the global execution context has that many threads.

Check out these posts they are examples of launching concurrent spark jobs with parallel collections.

[Cache and Query a Dataset In Parallel Using Spark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47726441/cache-and-query-a-dataset-in-parallel-using-spark/47733522#47733522)

[Launching Apache Spark SQL jobs from multi-threaded driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47842048/launching-apache-spark-sql-jobs-from-multi-threaded-driver)